# Tabbing multiple lines of code on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, code-formatting

Can I tab multiple lines of code on Stack Overflow?

When I copy and paste code into the code sample part, the alignment throughout the code is usually always off.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, select the text to tab & then press `Ctrl+K` or click the **Code Sample** link above the editor.
[image]